# Use getRange with one of the two elements inside Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, shadow-dom

I'm trying to get the common offset parent of two given DOM nodes, it works flawlessly when both nodes are inside the document, but it doesn't when one of them is in a Shadow DOM.

```js
function isOffsetContainer(element) {
    return element.firstElementChild.offsetParent === element
}


function findCommonOffsetParent(element1, element2) {
    const range = document.createRange();
    if (element1.compareDocumentPosition(element2) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING) {
        range.setStart(element1, 0);
        range.setEnd(element2, 0);
    } else {
        range.setStart(element2, 0);
        range.setEnd(element1, 0);
    }

    const { commonAncestorContainer } = range;
    
    // When one of the two elements is inside Shadow DOM, the `commonAncestorContainer`
    // returned is actually one of the two given elements in the range... 
    // For demo purposes, we detect this situation and we `console.log` it
    if ([element1, element2].includes(commonAncestorContainer)) {
      console.log('Shadow DOM ');
    } else {
      if (isOffsetContainer(commonAncestorContainer)) {
          return commonAncestorContainer;
      }

      const offsetParent = commonAncestorContainer && commonAncestorContainer.offsetParent;

      if (!offsetParent || offsetParent && offsetParent.nodeName === 'BODY') {
          return window.document.documentElement;
      }

      return offsetParent;
    } 
}


// Demo code
const reference = document.createElement('div');
reference.className = 'reference';
reference.innerText = 'reference';

const shadowParent = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(shadowParent);
document.body.appendChild(reference);
const shadow = shadowParent.createShadowRoot();
document.body.appendChild(shadow);

const popper = document.createElement('div');
popper.className = 'popper';
popper.innerText = 'popper';
shadow.appendChild(popper);

findCommonOffsetParent(popper, reference);
```

```css
.popper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.reference {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

How can I make `createRange` work with Shadow DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a range like this because the two elements are in different node trees.

According to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#ranges-and-selections):

> Selection is not defined. Implementation should do their best to do what's best for them. Here's one possible, admittedly naive way:
>
> Since nodes which are in the different node trees never have the same root, there may never exist a valid DOM range that spans multiple node trees.
>
> Accordingly, selections may only exist within one node tree, because they are defined by a single range. The selection, returned by the window.getSelection() method never returns a selection within a shadow tree.
>
> The getSelection() method of the shadow root object returns the current selection in this shadow tree.

As a consequence, you should define 2 ranges: one in the document DOM tree and another in the shadow DOM tree.

At the beginning of your function `findCommonOffsetParent()`, you should start to test if the elements are in a shadow DOM or not by using `getRootNode()`:

```
if ( element1.getRootNode().host ) 
   //in a shadow DOM
else
   //in the main document
```

Note that depending on your use case, you could have nested Shadow DOM so maybe you'll have to search Shadow roots recursively...

But in some simple situations (like in your example), it should be quite easy to deal with 2 ranges.

To get the common ancestor:

```
var shadow_host1 = element1.getRootNode().host 
var shadow_host2 = element2.getRootNode().host

if (shadow_host1 ) element1 = shadow_host1
if (shadow_host2 ) element2 = shadow_host2

//create range...
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with a similar solution https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/pull/201/files#diff-3841f93aefe44e3ce876c730b18768d7R22

Comment: OK you were faster than me!

Comment:  At least now I know my solution isn't that weird because at least another person in the world ended up with the same thing, eheh.

Comment: There's a proposal currently in development to extend the Selection API to properly handle Shadow DOM. See https://twitter.com/bocoup/status/1459120675390689284?s=20